# Loading a specific file from a module in node

Tags: node.js, git, unit-testing, npm

I wrote a module, [simpledblayer-mongo](https://github.com/mercmobily/simpledblayer-mongo). The module depends on [simpledblayer](https://github.com/mercmobily/simpledblayer) (it provides the DB-specific functions).

I am having a problem with unit testing. The problem here is that:

- `simpledblayer-mongo` gets the list of tests from `simpledblayer` (the `test.js` file)
- using GIT it's easy to define a "submodule" in `simpledblayer-mongo` and make sure that the submodule is placed under node_modules. So, the file with all the tests will be in node_modules/simpledblayer/tests
- With NPM, I define `simpledblayer` as a `devDependency`. No real need, since `simpledblayer` IS needed by `simpledblayer-mongo` regardless, as a straight dependency

The problem I am having is this: a user might get the module from GIT (the module will guaranteed to be in node_modules/simpledblayer) or NPM (the module might be placed either in node_modules, or it might actually be deduped/etc. and it might be anywhere, really).

I need to load `simpledblayer`'s `test.js` file *regardless* if where it is (as long as `simpledblayer` itself is require-able as a module). Any hint on getting a specific file from a module, regardless of what the module's path is?

Thanks!

Merc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`require.resolve()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_require_resolve) which returns an absolute path to the `main` property value (from the module's package.json) of the module name you pass in. From there, you can use the `path`/`fs` modules to help get to the right path, relative to the absolute path returned by `require.resolve()`.

So if `simpledblayer` has `main: 'index.js'` in its package.json, `require.resolve('simpledbplayer')` might return something like `/home/foo/project/node_modules/simpledblayer/index.js`.

Comment: Great idea, fantastic, that's exactly what I did. Thanks!